# Representing Solutions to Homogeneous System Proof Help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m attempting to prove the following theorem

> If $x_1, \space \ldots \space,  x_n$ is a linearly independent set of solutions to the $n $ x $ n$ system $x’ = \space A(t)x$,  then the general solution to the system is:
>
> $$x = c_1 x_1 \space + \space \ldots \space + \space c_n x_n$$

Now I believe that the proof of this theorem consists of two parts. First it must be shown that the vector functions of the form $c_1 x_1 \space + \space \ldots \space + \space c_n x_n$ are solutions to $x’ = Ax$, but then it must be shown that all solutions to the system are of this form.

I don’t have any trouble proving the first part, but I’m having difficulty showing that all solutions are of the form $c_1 x_1 \space + \space \ldots \space + \space c_n x_n$. Can anyone out there help me understand this portion of the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y$ is any solution to the system, then you can find $c_1,\dots,c_n$ such that $y-(c_1x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n)$ is a solution vanishing at zero. Now, the function that is identically zero is also a solution to the system, vanishing at zero. So you appeal to the theorem that says that a solution is uniquely determined by the initial conditions to deduce that $y-(c_1x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n)=0$.

Comment: Thanks! This actually makes sense to me.